# Is it possible to remove the Visual Studio IDE, but keep the build tools?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide, uninstallation

I am currently using VS2015, but I mean that rather loosely. I'm more into Atom or even Notepad++ as an IDE, and would rather do without the massive amount of disk space that the VS IDE appears to take up. I understand that some people appreciate it, but I personally find it unhelpful and often impeding.

However, keeping the build tools (compilation and linking chains), accessible at minimum via terminal, is very important for what I do. My problem is only with the overly bulky and unused IDE, which is in theory a separate product.

Is it possible for me to remove the VS2015 IDE, but keep the build tools intact? How would I go about doing this? Would doing so interfere with the operation of any VS-related tools (Android Studio, Unreal, Unity, etc.?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it all really depends - are you targeting the .net framework? .net core?

Comment: I do 90% of my programming on Linux Mint; the only thing I jump into Windows for is Unity, and occasionally Unreal. Which specific services they use, I'm not entirely clear on. If this is just a bad idea and I should leave it alone, that's a valid response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove VS2015 and download build tools from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.